# How to fix the useless 'favicon.ico page not found' log message?

Tags: 7, theming, debugging

Why is Drupal looking for it in the root dir in first place? The favicon is always placed inside theme at `sites/all/themes/mytheme/`, but it's looking for `favicon.ico` inside home `/` dir.

When browsing website it spams the log error message in the `Recent log messages` page.

Comment: Can you please apply [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/favicon404-174940-92.patch) for error message to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a Drupal bug, but a browser bug (I think Firefox might be a culprit)

The best way I found to fix it is to put:

```
<Location /favicon.ico>
  ErrorDocument 404 "No favicon"
</Location>
```

This code should work in your vhost file or should also work in the .htaccess file, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html for more details

Comment: It's a feature (not a bug) of all major browsers - if the page lacks an explicit favicon set in meta, the browser will query domain/favion.ico by convention. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#How_to_use has more details

Comment: Either way it's not a Drupal bug :)

Comment: Although adding this to .htaccess gives 500 Internal Server error.